Morera's Theorem for every circle
There is an article which prove that

$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, and $\int_C f(z) dz=0$ for every circle on $\mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is holomorphic.

https://anhngq.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/a-generalization-of-the-morera%E2%80%99s-theorem/
This proof uses that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be domain.
I want to know  if the following statement is correct：

$f$ is continuous on $D$, and $\int_C f(z) dz=0$ for every circle $C\subset D$ . Then $f$ is holomorphic on $D$.

Is there contradiction of this statement?

what do you mean? if the statement is correct on C , why not correct on D under the condition that $D \subset C$

That is because second statement's assumptions are "$f$ is continuous on "$D$" " and "every circle $C\subset D$ ". I've corrected my second claim, which was probably misleading due to the confusing way I wrote it.

If $f$ is $C^1$, then Green theorem will tell us $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation.
For a general continuous $f$, first we take a compact set $K\subset D$ and an open set $D'\subset K$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\operatorname{dist}(K,\partial D)> \delta$. We restrict $f$ to $K$.
Let $\eta:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be a smooth mollifier supported on $|z|\leq 1$. For any $x\in K$,  $0<\varepsilon<\delta$, let
$$f_{\varepsilon} (x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\eta(\frac{y}{\varepsilon})f(x-y)dy$$
This is well-defined since $\eta(\frac{y}{\varepsilon})$ is supported on $|y|\leq \varepsilon$, which means $f_{\varepsilon}$ does not depend on the value of $f(x)$ at points whose distance with $x$ is larger than $\delta$.
By the property of mollifiers, we know that $\{f_{\varepsilon}\}$ is smooth and uniformally converges to $f(x)$ on $K$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.
Now for any circle $C\subset D'$, we have
$$\int_Cf_{\varepsilon}(z)dz=\int_{C}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\eta(\frac{y}{\varepsilon})f(z-y)dydz=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\eta(\frac{y}{\varepsilon})(\int_{C}f(z-y)dz)dy=0$$
Hence $f_{\varepsilon}$ is holomorphic on $D'$. Since $f_{\varepsilon}$ uniformally converges to $f$ on $K$, according to Weierstrass' theorem, $f$ is holomorphic on $D'$.
Since both $K$ and $D'$ are arbitary, we conclude that $f$ is holomorphic on $D$.
I think this is similar to the proof you offered.

Thank you for your answer. I have an question. Why is $f_\epsilon$  holomorphic? Would it be sufficient to make the same argument as the last part of the proof in the link? https://anhngq.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/a-generalization-of-the-morera%E2%80%99s-theorem/

Because $f_{\varepsilon}$ is smooth and the integrals along any circles are $0$.

Let me check. Is your answer a proof of the second assertion of my question?
